# Background sound is stopped after some time

Tags: android, background-music

I have created a small android application in user guesses a word by clicking letters i have created small button for every letter(keyboard type thing).For correct letter guess it plays one file and wrong one it plays another file after guessing whole word correctly it clears the screen and provides another word to guess.The music is playing for some letter guess and after sometime it stops if i continue to play the game after guessing some words it again starts playin . What is the reason for it?? My phone problem or code problem or music file problem please reply me as soon as possible 
here is my code:

```
public void music(){
MediaPlayer player = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.test_cbr);player.start();

}
```

Comment: Why have you not marked any of the answers on you question? Did you not get any satisfactory answers yet? Please read this - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 0):

Is there another event occurring on the device that may be requesting the device speakers? Check out the logcat and if you can test on another device. If it occurs on more than one device it's likely something wrong with the app, but it may be the device.

Comment: i have edited my post please have a look one more time

Comment: Yeah, there's not enough information to go off of. From the edit it seems like there's something wrong with the app logic.

Comment: No, the program code. Obviously there's more code than the music method, and maybe things are being called multiple times, out of order in a way that you're not realizing. It's hard to tell without seeing it.